# AND/OR based on variable value in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to use AND/OR between the conditions in a stored procedure, and the decision is dependent on the parameter value whether it was 0 (AND) or 1 (OR)

Can anyone help me with this please, i guess this is an easy thing to do but i can't seem to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you have come up with so far?

Comment: You're probably better off doing 2 separate queries or dynamic SQL for this if the columns are indexed. The best plan for `OR` is likely to be quite different from that for `AND`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way (on first glance) would be to concatenate the query string using dynamic SQL, but dynamic SQL has its issues.
See [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for an in-depth explanation.

So I would try to avoid dynamic SQL, which is no big deal if your queries are not too complex.
The easiest way is just to fire two different queries depending on the parameter value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest
    @AndOr bit
AS
BEGIN

    if @AndOr = 0 begin 

        select * from YourTable where foo = 1 and bar = 2

    end
    else begin

        select * from YourTable where foo = 1 or bar = 2

    end

END
```

This is of course an example with a very simple query.
If you have lots of queries, or if your queries are very complex, this might not be the best solution because it forces you to duplicate all queries...but as always, it depends :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can implement your logic on a `CASE` statement. Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MySP @OrAnd BIT
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE   CASE WHEN Condition1 AND Condition2 AND @OrAnd = 0 THEN 1
            WHEN (Condition1 OR Condition2) AND @OrAnd = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
END
```

Answer (score 2):

If you convert the simple conditions' boolean results into numeric ones (`0` or `1`), you will be able to use your parameter in the following way:

```
(
  (CASE WHEN condition1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ^ @AndOr)
  &
  (CASE WHEN condition2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ^ @AndOr)
) ^ @AndOr = 1
```

Here `@AndOr` is your parameter, `^` is the Transact-SQL bitwise *exclusive OR* operator, `&` stands for the bitwise *AND* in Transact-SQL, and the `CASE` expressions are used to convert the boolean results into `0` or `1`.

If `@AndOr = 0` (which means we want `AND` between the conditions), the above expression effectively boils down to this:

```
case1 & case2 = 1
```

because `X XOR 0` yields `X` and so neither individual values of `case1` and `case2` nor the entire result of the `&` operator are not affected by the `^` operators. So, when `@AndOr` is `0`, the result of the original expression would be equivalent to the result of `condition1 AND condition2`.

Now, if `@AndOr = 1` (i.e. `OR`), then every `^` operator in the expression returns the inverted value of its left operand, in other words, negates the left operand, since `1 XOR 1 = 0` and `0 XOR 1 = 1`. Therefore, the original expression would essentially be equivalent to the following:

```
¬ (¬ case1 & ¬ case2) = 1
```

where `¬` means negation. Or, converting it back to the booleans, it would be this:

```
NOT (NOT condition1 AND NOT condition2)
```

According to one of [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws),

```
(NOT A) AND (NOT B) = NOT (A OR B)
```

Applying it to the above condition, we get:

```
NOT (NOT condition1 AND NOT condition2) = NOT (NOT (condition1 OR condition2)) =
= condition1 OR condition2
```

So, when `@AndOr` is `1`, the expression given in the beginning of my answer is equivalent to `condition1 OR condition2`. Thus, it works like expected based on the value of `@AndOr`.

Answer (score 0):

Having the `input parameter` you can use a [`IF clause`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933214%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to make different `selects`.

`If input parameter = 0` make the `AND conditions`, otherwise make the `OR conditions`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any particular elegant way to do it.  So here's the straightforward approach

```
create function myfun (@parm1 int, @parm2 int, @andor int) returns int
begin
if (@andor = 0 AND  @parm1 = 99 AND @parm2 = 99) return 1
else if (@andor = 1 AND (@parm1 = 99 OR @parm2 = 99)) return 1
return 0
end
go
select dbo.myfun(99,98,0) -- AND condition should return 0
select dbo.myfun(99,98,1) -- OR condition should return 1
select dbo.myfun(98,98,0) -- AND condition should return 0
select dbo.myfun(98,98,1) -- OR condition shoujld return 0
```